# Unable to connect with Hibernate 3, C3p0, and MySql running in secure-auth mode

Tags: mysql

I am running Hibernate 3, C3p0 0.9, and MySql 5.5, and Connector/J 5.1.18. I would like to run MySql with secure-auth=TRUE to use 41 byte hashed passwords. When doing so, I can successfully connect when manually coding the connection using standard JDBC:

```
Driver d = (Driver) Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
            .newInstance();
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://<ip address>:3306", "user", "password");
```

But I cannot connect in the hibernate/c3p0 environment. Reverting back to secure-auth=FALSE (and of course changing the passwords on the MySql end) solves the problem.

Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

EDIT: Same error with the default hibernate connection pool. So I don't think this is a C3P0-specific error.